# What are the 3 Offices of President in America?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, congress

Upon deeper research into the Constitution and Articles of Confederation, I found there are 3 Offices of President. The actual "Office of President" is for the actual sitting President. But if you take a closer look into these documents, it seems only a President who takes oath under article VI can fill that office, not the oath under article II.

The other two offices are, "Office of the President of the United States" and "Office of the President of the United States of America." It's clear enough to see these are different offices, but if I understand it correctly, the other two are reserved for appointment, and only by someone sitting in the actual "Office of President," under article VI, not II.

I find it extremely important to know, because if that's the case, then no one has ever filled the actual "Office of President" ever.

The only reason I could see for that is if a President wanted to have the power of taxation, which only congress assembled has, and not a President in the actual office.

And if that's true, than all Presidents have been mere employees of congress.

There are definitely 3 offices, so then whom would the other two be reserved for? The vice President and someone else perhaps? Maybe two trusted cabinet members? The President elect before reaching the actual office?

Seeing how most Americans don't even know there's a difference between the "United States" and "United States of America, this isn't going to be something anyone can answer. If I'm right, and I suspect I am, then not even Constitutional experts understand it. So if someone with real actual knowledge could help answer or verify this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful to quote the portions of the Constitution that you believe support your question. For example, you used a quoted "Office of President" from Article VI, yet that text doesn't seem to appear anywhere in Article VI.

Comment: I'll add my voice to that of @Geobits and ask for a citation to support your assertion that there is a difference between "the United States" and "the United States of America."  I am among the supposed majority of Americans, having been under the impression that the only difference is that one is a shorter way and the other a more precise way to refer to the same thing.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @phoog I suppose an argument could be made that there's a difference between the "united States" and  the "United States", but this has only ever been held as sort of a philosophical difference than an actual legal difference. That's the most reasonable explanation I could think of, but it doesn't fit how the question is actually written.

Comment: The articles of confederation had a President of Congress and no executive President, I think that's what OP is talking about. I also think OP thinks the articles of confederation are still a controlling factor of the government which is leading to the confusion.

Comment: You say "not even Constitutional experts understand it" and then "if someone with real actual knowledge could help answer or verify this". Experts on the Constitution are the ones with "real actual knowledge", can you explain what you expect as an answer? Until then I'm VTC as not a good faith question.

Comment: "There's a difference between the 'United States' and 'United States of America'". No, there's not. What in the world are you talking about? *You* are the one who seems to be very confused here.

Answer (score 4):

The Articles of Confederation are not law in the United States. (and no it doesn't matter if I write "United States of America" instead.) The Government under the Articles of Confederation ended with the adoption of the U.S. Constitution. There is only one presidential office in the modern United States.

Under the Articles of Confederation the President was a member of Congress, essentially equivalent to the modern speaker of the house, and there was no executive branch. This office was actually filled many times, but they are not usually counted as Presidents of the United States since it was such a radically different position.